# JS array works for one function but not in another function

Tags: javascript, html

My JS kung fu is non-existent so I come asking for help. I have a form.php page in which I have about 20 input fields; however, if one radio button is clicked more than half of those input fields need to be disabled. Here's what I have so far:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // create an array of all elementId's that need to be disabled/enabled based on whether radio button TR 280 or 284 is selected
    let fieldsAffected = [ 'f2Cct2Or4Wire2W', 'f2Cct2Or4Wire4W', 'f3Cct2Or4Wire2W', 'f3Cct2Or4Wire4W', 'f4Cct2Or4Wire2W', 'f4Cct2Or4Wire4W' ];

    function eqptTypeVal() { // FUNC to check the state of eqptType when page first loads and disabling/enabling required fields as necessary
      var rs = document.querySelector( 'input[ name = "eqptType" ]:checked' ).value;
      if ( rs == '280' ) {
        for ( let i = 0; i < fieldsAffected.length; i++ ) {
          document.getElementById( fieldsAffected[ i ] ).setAttribute( 'disabled', true );
        } // close FOR
      } else {
        for ( let i = 0; i < fieldsAffected.length; i++ ) {
          document.getElementById( fieldsAffected[ i ] ).removeAttibute( 'disabled' );
        } // close FOR
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC eqptTypeVal
    window.onload = eqptTypeVal;

    $( document ).ready( function() { // FUNC to monitor 280 radio button and when clicked disable the elementIds in array fieldsAffected
      $( '#eqptType280' ).click( function() {
        for ( let i = 0; i < fieldsAffected.length; i++ ) {
          $( fieldsAffected[ i ] ).setAttribute( 'disabled', true );
        } // close FOR
        /*
        $( '#f2Cct2Or4Wire2W' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        $( '#f2Cct2Or4Wire4W' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        $( '#f3Cct2Or4Wire2W' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        $( '#f3Cct2Or4Wire4W' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        $( '#f4Cct2Or4Wire2W' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        $( '#f4Cct2Or4Wire4W' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
         */
      });
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    $( document ).ready( function() { // FUNC to monitor 284 radio button and when clicked enable the elementIds in array fieldsAffected
      $( '#eqptType284' ).click( function() {
      for ( let i = 0; i < fieldsAffected.length; i++ ) {
        $( fieldsAffected[ i ] ).setAttribute( 'disabled', false );
      } // close FOR
      /*
        $( '#f2Cct2Or4Wire2W' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
        $( '#f2Cct2Or4Wire4W' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
        $( '#f3Cct2Or4Wire2W' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
        $( '#f3Cct2Or4Wire4W' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
        $( '#f4Cct2Or4Wire2W' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
        $( '#f4Cct2Or4Wire4W' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
       */
      });
    }); // close docReady FUNC
  </script>
```

The JS actually works as required without the **fieldsAffected** array, using the commented out blocks in the lower two JS functions. But because I will have a longish list of elementIds to disable if the *280* radio button is selected then I want to use an array and loop to manage the disabling-enabling of the affected elementIds.

The array must be good because it is used in first JS function to check whether or not the *280* radio button is selected, depending on mysql data, when the page first loads, disabling-enabling the elementIds in the array as intended. But then clicking on either the *280* or *284* buttons thereafter, using the same array in the following two JS functions, no change in the array's elementIds occurs when either the *280* or *284* radio buttons are clicked after initial page load.

But the 2nd and 3rd functions in which the array does not seem to work must be ok, because without the array, and all the elementIds listed out one by one, the input fields do disable-enabled whenever the *280* or *284* radio buttons are clicked.

But I really know nothing about JS. Can anyone help point out some likely nuances of the language lost in my hacking together the array and functions I pasted above?

**<=== HTML added ===>**

```
<fieldset class="fieldsetToneRemote">
      <legend>Eqpt ID</legend>
      <div class="formRowDiv">
        <label>
          <span>Eqpt Type:</span>
          <input type="radio" id="eqptType280" name="eqptType"  value="280"
            <?php
            if ( $_SESSION[ 'eqptType' ] == "280" ) {
                echo ' checked';
              }
            ?>
          >
          <span class="radioLabel">280</span>
          <input type="radio" id="eqptType284" name="eqptType" value="284"
            <?php
            if ( empty( $_SESSION[ 'eqptType' ] ) || is_null( $_SESSION[ 'eqptType' ] ) ) {
              echo ' checked';
            } elseif ( $_SESSION[ 'eqptType' ] == "284" ) {
                echo ' checked';
              }
            ?>
          >
          <span class="radioLabel">284</span>
        </label>
      </div><!-- close formRowDiv -->
```

Comment: $("#"+fieldsAffected[ i ] ) to select by ID

Comment: fieldsAffected array is IDs,First function works cause you have JS document.getElementById, for Jquery click trigger you need to prepend "#" in jquery to select element with IDs in your array OR if possible genrate array like [ '#f2Cct2Or4Wire2W', '#f2Cct2Or4Wire4W'...etc.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the heads up on including elementId symbol `#` concat; however, I added it to the lower two functions but the problem still persists.

Comment: Why not use either JS or Jquery in whole code?

Comment: @fakerooted : You need to change this line :$( fieldsAffected[ i ] ).setAttribute( 'disabled', false ); to : $( '#'+fieldsAffected[ i ] ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: @JoshulSharma although I knew I was going to need some JS voodoo to achieve what I want, I am still **very** hazy on the different flavors of JS to achieve the same end.

Comment: @JoshulSharma great catch. I orginally had used the `attr` keyword but changed to `setAttribute` while trying to figure things out before asking for help. Changing that back to `attr` as you suggest, and probably concatting the `#` to the array elements in the loop fixed my problem I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. do not have window.onload AND document.ready
2. DRY - don't repeat yourself
3. you are missing the "#" in front when you use jQuery to select IDs
4. I use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) which reduces the code and complexity
5. do not remove a property you want to toggle

```js
// create an array of all elementId's that need to be disabled/enabled based on whether radio button TR 280 or 284 is selected
var fieldsAffected = ['f2Cct2Or4Wire2W', 'f2Cct2Or4Wire4W', 'f3Cct2Or4Wire2W', 'f3Cct2Or4Wire4W', 'f4Cct2Or4Wire2W', 'f4Cct2Or4Wire4W'];

function eqptTypeVal() { // FUNC to check the state of eqptType when page first loads and disabling/enabling required fields as necessary
  var rs = $('input[name="eqptType"]:checked').val() == 280;
  $.each(fieldsAffected, function(i, val) {
    $("#" + val).prop('disabled', rs);
  })
} // close FUNC eqptTypeVal

$(function() { // when page loads
  eqptTypeVal(); // run the function
  // when either radio is clicked, run the function
  $('input[name="eqptType"]').on("click", eqptTypeVal);
}); // close docReady FUNC
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="eqptType" value="280" checked/>280</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="eqptType" value="284" />284</label><br/>
<input id="f2Cct2Or4Wire2W" /><br/>
<input id="f2Cct2Or4Wire4W" /><br/> 
<input id="f3Cct2Or4Wire2W" /><br/> 
<input id="f3Cct2Or4Wire4W" /><br/> 
<input id="f4Cct2Or4Wire2W" /><br/> 
<input id="f4Cct2Or4Wire4W" /><br/>
```

Comment: that sure is a great reduction in what I am sure I bloat-hacked. But I can't seem to get this to work. The fields in the array neither disable when the page loads and _280_ is selected, nor do the disable when the _284_ button is clicked and then the _280_ radio button is again selected. But the few alterations made from above comments got everything in my bloat-code working as intended. Any furthers suggs here and I'd love to go with the more streamlined ed.

Comment: Just remove my typo. I had `$.each(fieldsAffected.length` instead of `$.each(fieldsAffected` - my code works now as intended

Comment: @mplungjan `.length` was the culprit. Streamlined code working just fine now.